# import and export not working when debug within vscode

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

system configuration

- Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.1
- vs code 1.18.0
- node 6.11.4
- babel 6.26.0

I want to text es6 feature import export keyword in a pure js file ( no *node_modules* folders)

create 2 files as below content

#### utility.js

```
export const generateRandom = () => {
    console.log('inside generate Random');
    return Math.random();
};
```

#### check.js

```
import { generateRandom } from './export';

console.log(generateRandom());
```

when hit F5 from *check.js* and select environmentnt > *Node.js*

it gives following error in debug console tab

```
/opt/parixan/import.js:1 (function (exports, require, module,
__filename, __dirname) { import { generateRandom } from './utility';
                                                              ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
```

In sublime text I can run the same code through custom javascript build system; But how do we run the same in vs code

below are the necessary files

#### .eslintrc

```
    {
        "env":
        {
            "browser": true,
            "node": true,
            "es6": true
        },
        "extends": "eslint:recommended",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "modules": true,
            "spread": true,
            "restParams": true
        },
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 6,
            "sourceType": "module"
        },
        "globals":
        {
            "angular": true,
            "module": true,
            "inject": true,
            "moment": true,
            "saveAs": true,
            "require": false
        },
        "rules":
        {
            "indent": [0, "tab"],
            "linebreak-style": [0, "unix"],
            "semi": [2, "always"],
            "no-console": "off"
        }
    }
```

#### jsconfig.json

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "target": "ES6",
            "module": "commonjs"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does node 6 support ES6 import?

Comment: I do not know but the same thing ( usage of  `export` `import` ) working fine in react app, so I was just checking it out of the project in general JS file.

Comment: Is the react app running in node?

Comment: yes. we use *package.json* and it runs on node.have *node_modules* folder in the project directory

Comment: @pro.mean Nodejs does not support es6 `imports`.

Comment: I use package.json and have node_modules in most projects, but most are not run in node. Consider using `require` instead of `import`.

Comment: I have updated node v to *9.2.0* but still same error ;  sublime-text 3 also throw same error

Answer (score 0):

As my macOS was updated and it stopped all installed plugin such as babel-node. that's why it stopped compiling js file which has latest es6 syntax. here is the steps to fix the issue

- install latest node

`nvm istall node`

- install babel-cli

`npm install babel-cli -g`

`which babel-node` will give full path which can be used but we will us `babel-node` instead of path

now configure both editors with following steps

#### VSCODE

- install [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)
- open User settings in vs code and add this line along with other settings

  ```
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
                "javascript": "babel-node"
    }
  ```
- now select the file and press *option + control + N* to run the code and see the output in the console

### Sublime Text 3

- create new build system or edit build system with following content, in my case I have added build system so the location is

*/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/node.sublime-build*

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "babel-node ${file}",
    "selector": "source.js" 
}
```

- select file and run *Ctrl +* B from sublime text and output of file will be displayed in the bottom.